# asp.net mvc checking model null or empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I  am passing object of model to view.I want to check if the model is null or empty.I have done something like this

```
  @if(Model.data !=null)
  {
     //display data
  }

  else
   {
    //no records
   }
```

The problem is how to check if model is empty or not because empty!=null.

Comment: It depends on the type of obejct you're instantiating. For example, if data is a list and you're creating a new empty List on its constructor it will never be null.

What type of object is Model?

Comment: object is IEnumerable

Comment: Can you show us how are you passing this object to the .cshtml? It's probably already instantiated which means it will never be null. Just to make sure try `if(Model != null && Model.data != null && Model.data.Count() > 0)`

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by LINQ

```
 @if(Model.Any()){  //display data }
```

**Good luck and success**